# Twig dynamic functions

Tags: php, twig

The Twig documentation notes the following approach for creating a dynamic function:

```
$twig->addFunction('*_path', new Twig_Function_Function('twig_path'));

function twig_path($name, $arguments)
{
    // ...
}
```

Since I already encapsulate this code within a function, I'd like to avoid creating a function within a function. How can I place 'function twig_path' outside of this scope and still load it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to encapsulate your extension in a class, then use `Twig_Function_Method` instead of `Twig_Function_Function`. For an example see [MarketplaceExtension](https://github.com/KnpLabs/marketplace/blob/master/src/Marketplace/Twig/MarketplaceExtension.php).